# Sidebar in google sheets using apps script not working

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to build a sidebar in my google sheet and assign to it a script to send an emails.
The problem is the title and close button displays correctly but the content of the sidebar is not displaying and it gives an error :
"n-sf2kk5ynt6qhvo6tzp2uamld3a63ce7qvtsloby-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com took too long to respond."

This is the code I used:

1. interface.gs

```
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .createMenu('Control Panel')
      .addItem('Email', 'showEmail')
      .addToUi();
}

function showEmail() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setTitle('Email Panel')
      .setWidth(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi() // Or DocumentApp or SlidesApp or FormApp.
      .showSidebar(html);
}
```

2.Page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>Hello World!</div>
    <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is the situation consistently reproducible? New sheet, new project, new  sidebar.

Comment: Have you tried using your web browser in incognito/private mode with all the extensions disable? Which web browser are you using?

Comment: @TheMaster Yes it's consistently reproducible, I've created a new spreadsheet and it still persists, I've tried running it through another google account and the issue is still there.

Comment: @Rubén Yes I tried in incognito mode and it still persists, I'm using chrome

Comment: try removing all the comments : `//or documentui....`

Comment: I've tried logging in using a different PC and everything is working fine, what could be causing this on my pc ?

Comment: Try clearing cookies, storage of your browser.

Comment: I've done that but still nothing changed

Comment: Check browser console logs in devtools

Comment: Unrecognized feature: 'ambient-light-sensor'.
Unrecognized feature: 'speaker'.
Unrecognized feature: 'vr'.

Jo {message: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit", name: "TransportError", stack: "TransportError: There was an error during the tran…/js/4285718584-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:194:247)"}

Comment: Unrecognized features aren't a problem. Anything else?

Comment: Jo {message: "There was an error during the transport or process…this request. Error code = 10, Path = /wardeninit", name: "TransportError", stack: "TransportError: There was an error during the tran…/js/4285718584-warden_bin_i18n_warden.js:194:247)"}

Comment: If you want to pursue this, file a bug report with code, screenshots to issuetracker. See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-apps-script/info) for more details.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will try doing that

Comment: Do note that that *Transport error* might not even be related. So focus on your actual problem instead of this error.

Comment: I've checked my console again now and found those two messages appeared :

dropping postMessage.. was from host https://docs.google.com but expected host https://n-sf2kk5ynt6qhvo6tzp2uamld3a63ce7qvtsloby-0lu-script.googleusercontent.com
ADGmqu9tc3jNuKUAp6_DBCzwT2yv1YjvgxhhsZj9JR7M=s48-c-mo:1 

----------------------------------------

GET https://lh3.google.com/u/6/ogw/ADGmqu9tc3jNuKUAp6_DBCzwT2yv1YjvgxhhsZj9JR7M=s48-c-mo 403

Comment: 1.Are you using `postMessage`? 2. Seems like you're using multiple accounts 6? `u/6`. That may be a issue.

Comment: 1) No I'm not using any postMessage I posted exactly the code I used in the script editor
2) I'm using only 2 accounts, and I tried logging in through three different browsers with only one account.

Comment: Ok.. Don't think these errors are specific enough to pinpoint a problem. Better post to issue tracker. Even then, as the issue's reproducibility is  contingent upon access to your pc, it might not get resolved. Still worth a try.

Comment: @TheMaster Thank you so much, I really appreciate you efforts, I posted the issue and will see what happens.

Comment: Link the issue to your question here. What about a different browser such as firefox?

Comment: Wow! it actually worked on firefox, I also tried connecting to a different wifi network and it worked normally without any issues on chrome, but on my home wifi it's still not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is solved now, weirdly it was a problem with my router so resetting the router solved it thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple sidebar script to send and email

```
function sendemaildialog() {
  var html='<html><body>';
  html+='<form><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email Address" /><br/><input type="text" name="subject" placeholder="Subject"/>';
  html+='<br/><textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="message"></textarea><br/><input type="button" value="Send" onclick="google.script.run.sendEmail(this.parentNode);"/></form>';
  html+='</body></html>';
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html));
}

function sendEmail(obj) {
  GmailApp.sendEmail(obj.email, obj.subject, obj.message);
}
```

Comment: I tried this code but still the same issue persists.

Comment: Well I tested it so it works for me you’re doing something wrong