# Script moves to LastRow but user needs to click before entering data

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My current environment: Chrome, Win10, Thinkpad also FF, Win10, PC

When calling a function from **a button** on a sheet - the following script works, enabling a new row to be added after the lastRow with data.

But, when I type anything in my keyboard, the entered data isn't inputted into the cell.

**The cell needs to be clicked before it accepts keyboard entries.**

However, when the same function is run **from the script editor** the user **does not** have to click in the cell for keyboard entries to be accepted. This is the action that I require.

I have tried the same in a new Spreadsheet and using a different browser and hardware with same outcome.

Is this a bug in App Script? Is there a workaround?

Here's the script:

```
function addVenue() {    
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Venues");       
var column = ss.getRange('A:A');
var values = column.getValues(); 
  
//loop down until Venue name cell blank
  var ct = 0;
  while ( values[ct] && values[ct][0] != "" ) {
    ct++;
  }
  ct++;  

 ss.getRange("A"+ct).activate();     
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand correctly. Do you want to insert a new row after the last row of the sheet or do you want to activate first blank cell and let the user enter data there

Comment: Yes it's the latter - activate first blank cell and let the user enter data there

Comment: I tested it and for me your code works fine. Can you share this spreadsheet with us?

Comment: Do you mean "The cell has a blue border on selection on `activate()`, but it doesn't have a blinking cursor"?

Comment: You also said you checked in your PC. [Edit] to include that environment details(PC browser,OS) as well. Also check in Firefox please.

Comment: @TheMaster - I've added my PC env info to original question - same outcome

Comment: Try clearing browser cache and/or resetting your network router(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63596005/)) as We can't reproduce this issue.

Comment: How is `addVenue()` called? From script editor or button or menu?

Comment: @TheMaster Button on sheet

Comment: Bitey Does the same happen if you do what @Marios did in his gif(call from script editor)?

Comment: @TheMaster - Running function from Script Editor WORKS!!!

Comment: @TheMaster I was sure he was still missing important information in his question. Glad the issue is finally resolved.

Comment: Not quite - WHY? Is this a bug in app script?

Comment: @Marios I'll accept your criticism but did not think that the method of calling a function affected the outcome (and have never experienced such a thing).

Comment: @Bitey do you also want to add a new row after the last row with data ?

Comment: Marios & especially TheMaster - I want to thankyou for your help so far (and sticking with it :)

Comment: If  the linked duplicate above doesn't satisfy you, [edit] to show why? Or ask a new question.

Comment: That's a useful (if heavyweight) approach - thanks for bringing it my attention. I'll implement something similar in next couple of days and comment back. cheers

Comment: Consider adding a answer to the duplicate question instead of editing your question.

Comment: SO is Q&A site, not a forum. We respect Q&A format of the posts, please don't add your answer in the question post. Instead, either edit your post to make it clear the difference with the duplicate and make your question open and then pst your answer, either post your answer on the duplicate target post

Answer (score 1):

### Update:

I don't think your current code works since it **doesn't add** a new row after the last row with content. This is why I post this solution to answer this part of the question as it also offers a substantial improvement over the solution in your question. The following code has been tested and worked on **google chrome (PC)** and it is executed from the **script editor**.

The cell was activated and the user is able to directly enter data (regardless of its size) in that cell and he **does not need to click on that cell**:

[image: example]

### Solution:

- If you want to add a row after the last row with content of column A:

  ```
  function addVenue() {

    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Venues"); 
    var filledRows = ss.getRange("A1:A").getDisplayValues().filter(String).length;
    ss.insertRowsAfter(filledRows, 1);
    ss.getRange(filledRows+1,1).activate()
  }
  ```

### Restrictions:

- This method will only work if column A does not contain empty cells
  in between the first and last row of content; as your solution makes
  the same assumption.

### References:

- [insertRowsAfter(afterPosition, nRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#insertrowsafterafterposition,-howmany)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220892/discussion-on-answer-by-marios-script-moves-to-lastrow-but-user-needs-to-click-b).